# PySFML and event with mouse crash an app

Tags: python, sfml

I tried to program the tic tac toe game with PySFML but when I click window by the mouse after some time (10 seconds) application crashes (freezing). Simple code:

```
from sfml import sf

w = sf.RenderWindow(sf.VideoMode(600,400),"pySFML Window")
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 400
w.size = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
w.clear(sf.Color.GREEN)
w.title = "Window"

while(True):

    if(sf.Keyboard.is_key_pressed(sf.Keyboard.ESCAPE)):
        w.close()

    w.display()
```

Is it a bug in pySFML? I don't have this problem in C++ and SFML library.
I use Python3.5 and newest version of PySFML.

Comment: I tried pysfml and it worked awful - when I was moving mouse then it can't stop receiving mouse events and it was freezing all loop.  Did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message ?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not perfect... Yes it freezing not crash (or crash by freezing). No logs. So this is a problem with this library?

Comment: I took example from webpage - and when I was moving mouse then it had too many events so it freezed until I stoped moving mouse. PyGame or Pyglet has no problem with events.

Comment: BTW: if you speak Polish then we can talk on Facebook: "[Python Poland](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpl/)" or "[Python: pierwsze kroki](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpierwszekroki/)"

Comment: Yes, I am on facebook now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is inherent to the behavior of SFML, not these bindings. You must have, somewhere, an event loop (which is for `event in windows.events: pass`) and your code will work.